# Python Django Celery, terminating running task not working

Tags: python, django, celery

I create an web app, where users can run multiple scripts (celery tasks).

I went through [this artcle](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/10/26/celery-execution-pool/) and found out that i have to use `--pool (prefork, eventlet or gevent)`  not `solo`  because more scripts can run in one time.

What i need is to be able to terminate the running task if user needs to do so therefore i need to use only `prefork` . I found that `eventlet and gevent`  do not have implemented revoke method.

Now the issue.
When i run `--pool`  with `eventlet or gevent` , the task is received and executed. But i cannot terminate it as said.
When i run `--pool`  with `prefork` , it should be able to terminate the task, but when i run the task it is only received but not even executed.

And the last think i do no realy understand. I tried to start with `--pole=solo`  just to try revoking tasks (but i cannot use this later, because i need to run more scripts in one time).
And revoke method here does nothing.

```
app.control.revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

So my question is what should i use, to be able to terminate tasks and to be able to run more tasks in one time.

**Update for Krukas:**

When I run celery by `celery -A TNS worker --loglevel=INFO --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat -Ofair --pool=gevent --concurrency=2`

and then in the app run the script celery shows

```
[2020-01-04 18:13:33,213: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: api.tasks.task_1[d4e37b3b-67a7-49b9-879f-5157bcc28585]
[2020-01-04 18:13:43,418: INFO/MainProcess] Task api.tasks.task_1[d4e37b3b-67a7-49b9-879f-5157bcc28585] succeeded in 10.202999999999975s: None
```

so the task was executed, when I run Celery by `celery -A TNS worker -l info --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat -Ofair --pool=prefork --concurrency=2`

the log shows

```
[2020-01-04 18:21:39,255: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: api.tasks.task_1[4071904e-e014-4075-828e-58a0a87c781f]
[2020-01-04 18:21:40,696: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 9708 calling self.run()
[2020-01-04 18:21:40,696: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 8428 calling self.run()
```

And the script is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this documentation for revoke https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#worker-persistent-revokes

There are two important things:

1. revoke only works with RabbitMQ or Redis broker.
2. If you don't have statedb enabled and your workers are restarted it will lose the revoke information.

Comment: Thanks for responce Krukas. I use RabbitMQ as a broker. And i also use ```CELERYD_STATE_DB = "celery_state.db"``` settings.

Comment: Have read you question again, I think you answered your own question that you need to use prefork if you want to use revoke. `but when i run the task it is only received but not even executed` Is this when calling revoke, because that's what revoke does. I don't know how many concurrency you want, but using prefork with more concurrency then CPU cores is fine as long as those tasks are not CPU intensive. It will probably consume more RAM then gevent/evenlet because of how Python multiprocessing works. Setup at work has 6 core with concurrency of 22, but we don't have CPU intensive tasks.

Comment: Tasks are not CPU intensive therefore i will have to use ```prefork``` as you agree. But the problem with prefork is that tasks are received by Celery, but Celery does not execute them. Therefore i cannot even try to revoke them.

Comment: Only changing the pool and then it didn't work. Whit received do you mean you see the task in the Celery console? When for me a tasks was not running it was either de broker was different (that is because of the way our settings is setup) or the tasks was not found, on Celery startup you should see list of tasks found by Celery.

Comment: I have edited my post for more details so it is more well-arranged.

Comment: In both cases celery see the task in the list when running celery