# Is there a way to revoke/terminate running tasks in Celery on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, celery, django-celery

The normal revoke(task_id, terminate=true) doesn't work reliably on windows. I was wondering if there was another way to terminate celery tasks?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59578977/python-django-celery-terminating-running-task-not-working